# I want to launch google maps Start driving mode via an intent through my app

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

I have searched over all the internet to find the intent for this but haven't been successful till now, all i have found up till now is the same old route intent, can someone here help me out. Attached along is the screen where i want my application to land.
[image: This is where i want my app to land]

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
String URL = "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&travelmode=driving&dir_action=navigate&destination=Ahmedabad";
Uri location = Uri.parse(URL);
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, location);
startActivity(mapIntent);
```